# Como pegar o valor digitado num input para depois adicioná-lo a uma URL em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, url, javascript-eventos

Estou criando uma *search bar* no meu localhost. A intenção é que, quando o usuário digitar o que ele gostaria de pesquisar, o valor fosse adicionado ao valor de `q` em, por exemplo:

```js
const solr = "http://localhost:8983/solr/csv_indexing";
let videoList = await fetch(solr + "/select?q=" + query.value);
```

E `query` seria o que o usuário digitou, assuma que casa foi digitado, ele seria redirecionado para o endereço: `"http://localhost:8983/solr/csv_indexing/select?q=casa".`

O que já tenho de estrutura em HTML é só uma área para escrever no centro de uma página não customizada por enquanto:

```html
<div class="caixa-busca">
    <input type="text" name="" class="buscar-txt" placeholder="Pesquisar..."/>
    <a class="buscar-btn">
        <i class="far fa-search"></i>
    </a>
```

Como obtenho esse resultado?

Comment: Você quer redirecionar o usuário? Não entendi muito bem a pergunta.

Comment: quero adicionar o que ele digitar no input ao final dessa url: `"http://localhost:8983/solr/csv_indexing/select?q=`

Comment: E a concatenação não funcionou? Presumo que por causa de eventuais caracteres especiais...?

Comment: Eu não sei como pegar o valor que foi digitado no input para adicioná-lo a url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para capturar o valor do `<input>`, você pode utilizar o `querySelector` para, a partir do seletor do campo, obter o seu objeto JavaScript e, em seguida, utilizar a propriedade `value` para obter o valor atual. Assim:

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('#search-submit');
const field = document.querySelector('#search');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log(field.value);
});
```

```html
<input id="search" type="text" />
<button type="button" id="search-submit">Buscar</button>
```

O problema é que, se você concatenar o valor diretamente a uma *query string* do URL, você pode acabar gerando um URL inválido. Por exemplo, se você concatenasse a string diretamente e o usuário tiver digitado algum caractere como `?` ou `&`, poderia invalidar seu URL, adicionar mais parâmetros, etc — o que é evidentemente um problema.

Portanto, você pode utilizar a função [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) antes de concatenar. Veja a diferença:

```js
const base = 'http://localhost:8983/solr/csv_indexing';
const query = 'foo&other_param=bar';

const withoutEncodeURIComponent = base + '/select?q=' + query;
const withEncodeURIComponent = base + '/select?q=' + encodeURIComponent(query);

console.log({ withoutEncodeURIComponent, withEncodeURIComponent });
```

Juntando tudo, você fica com algo como:

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('#search-submit');
const field = document.querySelector('#search');

const baseURI = 'http://localhost:8983/solr/csv_indexing';

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const query = encodeURIComponent(field.value);
  const url = baseURI + '/select?q=' + query;
  
  // Faça algo com `url`. (O `fetch`, por exemplo):
  console.log(url);
});
```

```html
<input id="search" type="text" />
<button type="button" id="search-submit">Buscar</button>
```

Uma outra opção para gerar o URL é utilizar o próprio construtor [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL):

```js
const url = new URL('http://localhost:8983/solr/csv_indexing/select');

// Adicionamos o parâmetro `q`. Ele já será automaticamente "escapado":
url.searchParams.append('q', 'foo');

// Obtem a URL:
console.log(url.toString());
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
const solr = "http://localhost:8983/solr/csv_indexing";

document.getElementById('btn-buscar').onclick = function() {
  let q = document.getElementById('txtbusca');
  let videoList = solr + "/select?q=" + q.value;
  /* window.location.url = videoList; */
  console.log(videoList);
};
```

```html
<input type="text" name="txtbusca" id="txtbusca" placeholder="">
<button id="btn-buscar">Buscar</button>
```